# Can MS Flow connect to a new excel file automatically when dropped in connected folder?

Tags: excel, power-automate

I have created a flow to 'Get Rows' from an excel table and email the values out, which is working correctly.

The issue I have, is that the data is extracted from a reporting tool into an excel file. Ideally, I would like to be able to drop the new file into the folder and MS Flow connect to this. Appreciate a table would need to be created, however is there a way this can be done?

I can certainly name the file the same as specified in the flow, however when I do this, I am forced to navigate to the directory to reselect the file in question. By having to do this, it takes a level of automation away.

Any ideas to get around this or an alternative way to approach it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where the Excel file is stored. Power Automate offers `When a file is created or modified` triggers for SharePoint and OneDrive that you can attach to a particular folder or an entire Document Library.

If you can make the Excel file have a named table in it before it hits SharePoint/OneDrive, that would be best. You could modify it after creation to have a table and the flow would trigger on that, but you would have flows that error out when the file is uploaded. Unfortunately there is only `When a file is created` and `When a file is create or modified` and not a `When a file is modified`.